# Installed Git, but accidentally deleted a file. Now I'm lost

Tags: git, bash

I am a total noob when it comes to coding in the command line and I was following a tutorial on Git. I installed it and followed the directions fully. However, after everything was set up, I must have accidentally deleted a file, as now I receive this when I enter Terminal:

```
Last login: Wed Jan  4 19:56:29 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/ryanbowlen/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/ryanbowlen/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
ryanbowlen ~ $ cd ~
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
ryanbowlen ~ $
```

I just want to get everything back to the basic Terminal, Git-free. Help?

Comment: I upvoted because you're learning and looking for help, but I think your question might be better suited to http://superuser.com/

Comment: Show us everything. What's the tutorial? What did you do? It looks like you made changes to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`; if so let us see those. And what makes you think you deleted a file without knowing it?

Comment: I ran through the "Using Git and Github" tutorial on Udacity. I feel like I deleted a file when removing some of the project files from a later module. I would show you everything, but I honestly don't know how. I am very unfamiliar with bash.

Comment: Okay, I tried to open the ~/.bash_profile and couldn't. So I used bits and pieces of what everyone here suggested. I used the download of Git and just manually put the files into the home folder and edited their names. As I couldn't "mv" the files in the terminal, I did it through Finder. Everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty hack. `touch /Users/ryanbowlen/git-completion.bash /Users/ryanbowlen/git-prompt.sh`. This should allow your profile to source an empty file.

Comment: Run the command `cat ~/.bash*` to show your profile files, and check `cat /etc/profile` as well. If it was recent enough, you can show what you did with the `history` command. `history | grep git` or `history | grep rm` both could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that reinstalling git will replace the file for you. Try this: An OSX Git installer is maintained and available for download at the Git website, at http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Assuming you're on Mac, which I'm guessing you are since you referenced Terminal.